# What are some good vpns clients for Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, 15.10, vpn

I need to know if there are any vpn clients recommendation for Linux it is hard to find any particular one?

Comment: VPNs are cross-platform. Do you mean VPN Clients?

Comment: Yes I do mean clients good secure clients.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in that [list](https://torrentfreak.com/anonymous-vpn-service-provider-review-2015-150228/). Some examples:

- [PRIVATE INTERNET ACCESS](https://bra.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/buy-vpn/)
- [TORGUARD](https://torguard.net/) [IPVANISH](https://www.ipvanish.com/?a_aid=start)
- [SLICKVPN](https://www.slickvpn.com/torrentfreak-anonymous-vpn)
- [IVPN](https://www.ivpn.net/)
- [PRIVATEVPN](https://privatevpn.com/)
- [PRQ](http://www.prq.se/?p=tunnel&intl=1)
- [EXPRESSVPN](https://www.expressvpn.com/)
- [MULLVAD](https://mullvad.net/en/)
- [BOLEHVPN](http://bolehvpn.net/)
- [NORDVPN](https://nordvpn.com/)
- [TORRENTPRIVACY](https://torrentprivacy.com/index.php?mod=v2_main_10)
- [PROXY.SH](https://proxy.sh/)
- [HIDEIPVPN](https://www.hideipvpn.com/)
- [BTGuard](https://btguard.com/)
- [OCTANEVPN](http://www.octanevpn.com/)
- [SMART
  DNS PROXY](https://www.smartdnsproxy.com/)

and so on...

You can easily use it with a gui interface as `network-manager-openvpn`, `network-manager-pptp` or `network-manager-vpnc`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-pptp network-manager-vpnc
```

For Gnome:

```
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

And make a setup as required by your vpn provider. After that, restart your network:

```
# /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

Comment: Put some in your answer. Copy and paste is perfectly fine, but just a link can be pretty useless if that link happens to go down.